# Help following step in spin geometry paper.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, spin-geometry

I was reading a paper regarding the [Dirac operator on embedded hypersurfaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0012262.pdf)  and can't follow a step taken on page 5. They're examining the [Schroedinger-Lichnerowicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lichnerowicz_formula) equation on a manifold $\Omega$ with boundary $\Sigma$.

> $$D^{*}D\psi=\bar{\nabla}^{*}\bar{\nabla}\psi+\frac{1}{4}\bar{R}\psi$$
>
> Consider the 1-forms:
>
> $$\alpha(X)=\langle\gamma(X)\bar{D}\psi,\psi\rangle,\beta(X)=\langle\bar{\nabla}_{X}\psi,\psi\rangle$$
>
> for any  $X\in\Gamma\left(T\Omega\right)$. It is clear that:
>
> $$\delta\alpha=\langle\bar{D}^{2}\psi,\psi\rangle-|\bar{D}\psi|^{2}$$
>
> because $\gamma$ acts by skew-symmetric endomorphisms for
> $\langle,\rangle$. Also
>
> $$\delta\beta=-\langle\bar{\nabla}^{*}\nabla\psi,\psi\rangle+|\bar{\nabla}\psi|^{2}$$
>
> hence, we obtain
>
> $$\delta\alpha+\delta\beta=|\bar{\nabla}\psi|^{2}-|\bar{D}\psi|^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\bar{R}|\psi|^{2}$$Integrating
> on $\Omega$ and applying the divergence theorem
>
> $$-\intop_{\Sigma}\langle\gamma(N)\bar{D}\psi+\bar{\nabla}_{N}\psi,\psi\rangle
>  d\Sigma=\intop_{\Omega}\left(|\bar{\nabla}\psi|^{2}-|\bar{D}\psi|^{2}+\frac{1}{4}\bar{R}|\psi|^{2}\right)d\Omega$$

Now initially I had thought that $\delta$ applied to the 1-forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ meant taking the variance as that seems to fit. If that's the case however I don't see how:

$$\intop_{\partial\Sigma}\left(\hat{n}\cdot\alpha\right)d\Sigma=\intop_{\Omega}\left(\delta\alpha\right)d\Omega$$

I then considered that maybe $\delta$ is meant to the the codifferential, which fits the last equation but doesn't seem to fit the definitions of $\delta\alpha$ and $\delta\beta$ above. Can someone please enlighten me as to what exactly they're doing here?

Comment: As far as I can see, it is the codifferential. There is a "local formula" for the codifferential:
$ \delta \alpha = -\sum_i \iota_{e_i} \nabla_{e_i} \alpha = - \sum_{i} (e_i(\alpha(e_i)) - \alpha(\nabla_{e_i}e_i)) $. Where $e_i$ is a local orthonormal frame and $\iota$ means contraction. (the second equation is then only for 1-forms) This should clarify the first two formulas?

Comment: @Jonas Thank you! I haven't been able to figure out how the authors formulas follow yet but they assure me in the above quoted text that "it is clear" lol!

Comment: @Jonas I haven't been able to figure out the initial equations, moreover I'm now realizing that that the Generalized Stokes theorem should only apply to the exterior derivative, not it's formal adjoint (the codifferential) So now I'm really lost as to what the authors were up to

Comment: For your stokes: You probably know the version with divergence of a vector field? With the formula from my first comment, you can figure out that $\delta \alpha = div(X_\alpha)$ where $X_\alpha$ is the vector field, which is dual to $\alpha$ via the metric. 
I don't have the time now to type up a proper answer,sorry.